# How do you set the default value for multiple selects on a page with vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a table of rows. Each row has a dropdown box. How can I specify the default value for each dropdown box in a row?

This is how I'm generating the selects:

```
<VDataTable
        v-model:expanded="expanded"
        :items-per-page="5"
        :headers="headers"
        :items="requests"
        item-value="id"
        class="elevation-1"
        show-expand
        :loading="loading"
    >
        <template v-slot:top>
            <VToolbar flat>
                <v-toolbar-title>Estimate Requests</v-toolbar-title>
            </VToolbar>
        </template>
        <template #item.customer_name="{ item }"> {{ item.raw.customer.fname }} {{ item.raw.customer.lname }} </template>
        <template #item.status>
            <v-select
                item-title="status"
                item-value="id"
                v-model="defaultSelected"
                :items="statuses"
            />
        </template>
        <template v-slot:expanded-row="{ columns, item }">
            <tr>
                <td :colspan="columns.length">
                    <address>{{item.raw.address}}<br />{{item.raw.city}}, {{item.raw.state}} {{item.raw.zip}}</address>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </template>
    </VDataTable>
```

My script looks like this:

```
<script>


export default {
    components: {Card},
    data () {
        return {
            expanded:[],
            headers: [
                { title: 'ID', align: 'start', key: 'id' },
                { title: 'Name', align: 'start', key: 'customer_name' },
                { title: 'Email', align: 'start', key: 'customer.email' },
                { title: 'Status', align: 'start', key: 'status' },
            ],
            defaultSelected:1
        }
    },

}
</script>
```

As expected, all selects currently default to the status that corresponds with id 1. How can I change it so that it defaults to the value of the status id for each row? Can I pass something inline? a v-if? should defaultValue return key value pages of ids and status ids?

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it you want the v-model to run for each row. This is easy to do, but you need to create an array beforehand. You can then assign default values for this array.

Check it. https://codesandbox.io/p/github/eguvenc/test/

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-row>
      <v-col cols="6">

      <VDataTable
        v-model:expanded="expanded"
        :items-per-page="5"
        :headers="headers"
        :items="requests"
        item-value="id"
        class="elevation-1"
        show-expand
        :loading="loading"
    >
        <template v-slot:top>
            <VToolbar flat>
                <v-toolbar-title>Estimate Requests</v-toolbar-title>
            </VToolbar>
        </template>
        <template #item.customer_name="{ item }"> {{ item.raw.customer.fname }} {{ item.raw.customer.lname }} </template>
        <template #item.status="{ item }">
            <v-select
              v-model="form[item.index].status"
              :items="statuses"
            />
        </template>
        <template v-slot:expanded-row="{ columns, item }">
            <tr>
                <td :colspan="columns.length">
                    <address>{{item.raw.address}}<br />{{item.raw.city}}, {{item.raw.state}} {{item.raw.zip}}</address>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </template>
    </VDataTable>

      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  components: {
    
  },
  data () {
    return {
        form: [
          { status: 1 },
          { status: 2 }
        ],
        statuses: [1, 2],
        requests: [
          { id: 1, name: "James Brown", email: "jb@example.com" },
          { id: 2, name: "Eli Brown", email: "eli@example.com" }
        ],
        expanded:[],
        headers: [
            { title: 'ID', align: 'start', key: 'id' },
            { title: 'Name', align: 'start', key: 'name' },
            { title: 'Email', align: 'start', key: 'email' },
            { title: 'Status', align: 'start', key: 'status' },
        ]
    }
  },
  computed: {

  },
  created() {

  },
  methods: {
   
  }, // end methods
}
</script>
```